# Check if a AnyClass variable is an extension or implementation of a class

Tags: swift

Having a variable of type AnyClass, is it possible to know if that type is an extension or implementation of another type?

For example:

```
var aClass: AnyClass = UIButton.self

// assuming a fictional operator "isOfType"
// Both UIButton and UILabel are subclasses of UIView
aClass isOfType UIButton // true
aClass isOfType UIView   // true
aClass isOfType UILabel  // false
```

One possible way to do this is creating an instance, but creating such instance may not be always desirable:

```
var aClass: AnyClass = UIButton.self

let buttonClass = aClass as? UIButton.Type
var aButton: AnyObject = buttonClass!()
aButton is UIButton // true
aButton is UIView   // true
aButton is UILabel  // false
```

Are there other means to check if a AnyClass contains a type that extends another type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `isSubclassOfClass` if the receiving class inherits from `NSObject`.

```
let c = UIButton.self
print(c.isSubclassOfClass(UIButton.self)) // true
print(c.isSubclassOfClass(UIView.self)) // true
print(c.isSubclassOfClass(UILabel.self)) // false
```

**Update:** Although `isSubclassOfClass` is defined in `NSObject`, it seems to be usable for Swift classes that don't explicitly derive from `NSObject` as well. The below works as expected in Xcode 7 beta 6.

```
class A {
}

class B: A {
}

class C {
}

let c: AnyClass = B.self
print(c.isSubclassOfClass(A.self)) // true
print(c.isSubclassOfClass(B.self)) // true
print(c.isSubclassOfClass(C.self)) // false
```

I believe that Swift classes that don't inherit from `NSObject` still share some of its methods for compatibility reasons. I couldn't find any official documentation on this, however, and Xcode won't even let me navigate to the declaration of `isSubclassOfClass` from the snippet above.

**Update 2:** An alternative that works regardless of whether the classes inherit from `NSObject` or not is to use `is` together with the `Type` property.

```
let c: AnyClass = UIButton.self        
print(c is UIButton.Type) // true
print(c is UIView.Type) // true
print(c is UILabel.Type) // false

let c: AnyClass = B.self
print(c is A.Type) // true
print(c is B.Type) // true
print(c is C.Type) // false
```

Comment: Neat, this is definitely helpful. Still i am wondering if there is a way to do this without the NSObject methods, or using directly the swift type syntax.

Comment: @LopSae Seems that `isSubclassOfClass` works for pure Swift classes as well (see my update).

Comment: @LopSae I think using `is` together with the `Type` property is probably the most *swifty* way of doing this (see my second update).

Comment: Excellent! Using `is Class.Type` looks like the proper way of doing this. Curiously `is Class.self` does not work, which is something i had tried before, and never though that `Class.Type` could be used as this.

Comment: @LopSae It's sort of not intuitive, I agree.